# Why does it render smooth?

Tags: rendering, sculpting

I know I did by mistake a key combination in sculpt mode but i dont know how to reset this. I just want a low poly image of this tiles: [image] but in sculpt mode and the rendert image (not render mode!) are smooth like u see in the picture [image]

Answer (score 2):

> I know I did by mistake a key combination in sculpt mode....

From looking at your image, and from your description, it sounds like you most likely pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or otherwise activated the [*Multi-resolution Modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html#multiresolution-modifier) while sculpting.

This modifier has separate preview/ sculpt and render settings much like the [Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) as seen in the left column of the modifier settings.

[image]

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html#levels):

> **Levels**
>
> The left column of settings control the general quality generated by
>   the modifier in various contexts.
>
> Preview
>
> Set the level of subdivisions to show in Object Mode. Sculpt
>
> Set the level of subdivisions to use in Sculpt Mode. Render
>
> Set the level of subdivisions to show when rendering. Quality
>
> How precisely the vertices are positioned (relatively to their theoretical position), can be lowered to get a better performance when
>   working on heavy meshes.

If the render and preview amounts do not match, you will see a different result when rendering, although performance may be improved with lower sculpt/ preview amounts in some cases.

In your specific situation however, needing a low-poly object you can simply remove the modifier. *(click the* <kbd>x</kbd> *icon*)

Comment: It was the Multi-resolution modifier, thanks!

Comment: Consider to accept the answer, if it did solve your issue @cabriocat How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour